# How to define query and body parameters in swagger in a single API call

Tags: json, node.js, yaml, swagger

The API has parameters in the body and query, I need to define this in swagger like below:

```
parameters: [
  {
    "name": "businessCode",
    "in": "query",
    "required": true,
    "type": "string",
  },
  {
    "name":"clientCode",
    "in":"query",
    "required":true,
    "type":"string",
  },
  {
    "name":"client",
    "in":"body",
    "required":true,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its easy and you have already given an example of that. Here is another proper example.

```
parameters: [{
      name: "id",
      description: "id of something",
      required: true,
      type: "Id",
      paramType: "query"
    },
    {
      name: "Body",
      description: "any data",
      required: true,
      type: "User", //define this model in model file
      paramType: "body"
    }]
```